# Change Vendor Directory Configuration in Laravel 8 / Composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-8

I’m trying to change the default vendor directory path configuration in my Laravel 8 project, but I’m stumbling in some problem.

So for, this is what I did:

File composer.json

```
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "vendor-dir": "php_modules/vendor"
    },
```

File public/index.php

```
require __DIR__.'/../php_modules/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Terminal (re-generate autoload files):

```
composer dump-autoload
```

When I serve the page (terminal: php artisan serve), I get this error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Illuminate\Foundation\Application" not found in K:\syncsystem\tecnologias\php\laravel\aula\laravel8\syncsystem-laravel8-v1\bootstrap\app.php:14 Stack trace: #0 K:\syncsystem\tecnologias\php\laravel\aula\laravel8\syncsystem-laravel8-v1\public\index.php(48): require_once() #1 K:\syncsystem\tecnologias\php\laravel\aula\laravel8\syncsystem-laravel8-v1\server.php(21): require_once('...') #2 {main} thrown in K:\syncsystem\tecnologias\php\laravel\aula\laravel8\syncsystem-laravel8-v1\bootstrap\app.php on line 14

Is there somewhere else I should change in order for it to work properly?

I tried to find information about changing this path in the web, but all suggestions were incomplete.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the path to the vendor folder in /artisan php file.

From:

`require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';`

To:

`require __DIR__.'/../php_modules/vendor/autoload.php';`